# how to append multiple img-child elements to a DOM element with JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to add multiple, same img-elements to a div element. Why can't I just use appendChild a couple times?

For instance:

```js
divelement.appendChild(imgelement);
divelement.appendChild(imgelement);
divelement.appendChild(imgelement);
```

will result in

```html
<div>
  <img></img>
</div>
```

But how can I achieve the following?

```html
<div>
  <img></img>
  <img></img>
  <img></img>
</div>
```

Comment: The `imgelement` needs to be a new instance. If you add the same child, it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way should work.

```
var div = document.getElementById('myId');
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      div.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `imgelement` needs to be a new instance. If you add the same child, it will do nothing.

```js
const divElement = document.querySelector('#target');
const imgElement = document.createElement('img');

divElement.append(imgElement); // Original reference
divElement.append(imgElement); // ^ Same reference
divElement.append(imgElement); // ^ Same reference
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

You need to create a new image instance for each append action:

```js
const divElement = document.querySelector('#target');
const createImgElement = () => document.createElement('img');

divElement.append(createImgElement());
divElement.append(createImgElement());
divElement.append(createImgElement());
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You are appending same child 3 times .

an working solution is here -

```js
const myParent = document.getElementById("someDiv");
const myImg1 = document.createElement("img");

myImg1.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
myParent.append(myImg1);
const myImg2 = document.createElement("img");

myImg2.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
myParent.append(myImg2);

const myImg3 = document.createElement("img");

myImg3.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
myParent.append(myImg3);
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#someDiv{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  margin:auto;
    display:flex;
}
img{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "someDiv">
  
</div>
```